# asyncio vs asyncore for custom server python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, asyncsocket, asyncore

I wanna build a custom server for some project and I don't know **whats the difference** between `asyncore` and `asyncio` server, **what** is better to use, and **why**

Comment: This note from the Python 3.7 asyncore docs give a hint: "This module exists for backwards compatibility only. For new code we recommend using asyncio."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`asyncore` is the "old", Python 2 way of doing some basic event-driven servers and clients (in other words, for doing asynchronous IO).

`asyncio` is the new, Python 3 module that provides a whole framework for doing asynchronous IO in general. It has much more features, including support for coroutines, which allow you to use keywords like `async def` and `await`, which improve readability of asynchronous code.

**In summary, `asyncio` is the way to go.** `asyncore` is not recommended in Python 3, which new projects should be using instead of Python 2. If you are stuck with Python 2, `asyncore` is a sane choice.

Comment: I would recommend avoiding `asyncore` even in Python 2 because it is almost never used and receives virtually no support from the community. In Python 2 one should probably best use [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) for asynchronous communication.